# Batch Copy Multiple Files to Multiple Folders

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file

I have multiple subfolders and would like to copy all the PDF documents that are in the main folder into the subfolders with a bat file.

For e.g. All the files are in "C:\Users\user\Box Sync\Batch" and I want to move them to all the available folders within the same path "C:\Users\ZGGroenewald\Box Sync\Batch\Folderx". The folder names will change constantly and I don't want to have to supply a folder list every time I want to run this operation.

Comment: And how to determine for each file to what folder it is to be placed in?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: What means "available folders" ? Your question is not clear.